# python os.system command skips spaces " " associated with awk in command

Tags: python, linux, awk, sh

```
os.system("cat syslog | grep -C 5 'Type: UNKNOWN' |grep 'INITIAL  VALUE = *' |awk '{a[$12]++ } END { for (b in a) { if (length(b) > 11) print $1 " " $2  " "  $3 " "  b }}' >> uniqueCode.txt")
```

the output of the above script is

```
Aug2722:45:3313452566773
Aug2722:45:3313452566376
```

but it must be

```
Aug 27 22:45:33 13452566773
Aug 27 22:45:33 13452566376
```

I have tried to add space with " " in awk but it is not working, wanted to know is there any way i can add the space

Comment: You should not use `cat`, both `grep` and `awk` can read file directly.  If you post output example of  `grep -C 5 'Type: UNKNOWN' ` we may be able to all this with just one `awk` command.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `"`

```
os.system("cat syslog | grep -C 5 'Type: UNKNOWN' |grep 'INITIAL  VALUE = *' |awk '{a[$12]++ } END { for (b in a) { if (length(b) > 11) print $1 \" \" $2  \" \"  $3 \" \"  b }}' >> uniqueCode.txt")
```